# Deserialize JSON created using custom getter and unwrapped object using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

This is a follow up question of an answer to Jackson [custom getters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9140202/3560643).

The solution works and creates proper JSON. The problem is deserialization. I have an unwrapped object with some attributes not shown in JSON but instead replaced by a new attribute (e.g. firstname+surname => name).

This is correctly serialized to

`{"age":22,"name":"Alex Doe"}`

This class can not be edited, so we rely on mixin.

The problem on deserialization is, that `PersonSerializer.setFullname()` is called before `PersonSerializer.setPerson()`, probably because attributes are deserialized before subobjects. Which forces me to have a `Person`-object created when `PersonSerializer` is created by the `ObjectMapper`. This `Person`-object is overwritten when age is deserialized with an `Person`-object only containing the age:

`firstName: null, surname: null, age: 22`

I could store `fullname` in `setFullname()` and fill it into `person` when `setPerson()` is called but this feels incorrect.

What is the proper way to solve this problem?

Code:

```
public final class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String surname;
    private int age;

    public Person() {
        super();
    }

    Person(final String firstName, final String surname, final int age) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
    }
 //getter and setter
}
```

Serialization helper and mixin based on the answer:

```
public class PersonSerializer {

    private Person person;

    public PersonSerializer() {
        super();
        person = new Person(); //needed, otherwise NPE in setFullname()
    }

    @JsonUnwrapped
    Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    //customer getter to join firstname and surname
    @JsonGetter("name")
    String fullName() {
        return person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getSurname();
    }

    @JsonSetter("name")
    public void setFullname(final String fullName) {
        final String[] s = fullName.split(" ");
        person.setFirstName(s[0]);
        person.setSurname(s[1]);
    }

    public void setPerson(Person p) {
        person = p;
    }
}
```

and

```
abstract class PersonMixin {

    @JsonIgnore String firstName;
    @JsonIgnore String surname;
}
```

Testcode:

```
public static void main(String[] args)

        throws JsonProcessingException {

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().addMixIn(Person.class, PersonMixin.class);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        final PersonSerializer alex = new PersonSerializer();
        alex.setPerson(new Person("Alex", "Doe", 22));
        final String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(alex);
        out.println(s);

        final Person newAlex = mapper.readValue(s, PersonSerializer.class).getPerson();
        out.println(String.format(
            "firstName: %s, surname: %s, age: %d",
            newAlex.getFirstName(),
            newAlex.getSurname(),
            newAlex.getAge()
        ));
    }
```

I searched for examples, documentation and StackOverflow but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code can be more simple:
What you need is a Wrapper of Person class since you can't edit it.

Person:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    
    private String surname;
    
    private int age;

}
```

Person Wrapper

```
public class PersonWrapper extends Person {
     
    private String name;
    
    public PersonWrapper() {
        super();
    }

    public PersonWrapper(String firstName, String surname, int age) {
        super(firstName, surname, age);
        name = getName();
    }

    public String getName() {
        this.name = getFirstName() + " " + getSurname();
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(final String name) {
        final String[] s = name.split(" ");
        setFirstName(s[0]);
        setSurname(s[1]);
    }
    
}
```

PersonMixIn:

```
public abstract class PersonMixIn {

    @JsonIgnore 
    String firstName;
    
    @JsonIgnore 
    String surname;
    
}
```

TEST:

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().addMixIn(PersonWrapper.class, PersonMixIn.class);
        final PersonWrapper alex = new PersonWrapper("Alex", "Doe", 22);
        final String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(alex);
        System.out.println(s);

        final Person newAlex = mapper.readValue(s, PersonWrapper.class);
        System.out.println(String.format(
            "firstName: %s, surname: %s, age: %d",
            newAlex.getFirstName(),
            newAlex.getSurname(),
            newAlex.getAge()
        ));
        
    }

}
```

result:

Serialization: {"age":22,"name":"Alex Doe"}

Deserialization: firstName: Alex, surname: Doe, age: 22

Comment: The `Person`-class is final and I can not extend from it.